# salt-minion Error in Uyuni Server. How to resolve this?

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying  to connect my uyuni server to my client via salt. I have the same versions of salt-master and salt-minion. I have a single salt-master.

However, I get the following errors. Please help me to find the solution.

Here is my salt-minion file (/etc/salt/minion.d/ uyuni.conf)

```
master: host.name.com
grains:
susemanager:
activation_key: "key"
server_id_use_crc: adler32
enable_legacy_startup_events: False
enable_fqdns_grains: False
```

salt-minion -l debug

```
[DEBUG ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf'
[DEBUG ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf
[DEBUG ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: host.name.com
[WARNING ] Insecure logging configuration detected! Sensitive data may be logged.
[DEBUG ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/minion
[INFO ] Setting up the Salt Minion " host.name.com "
[INFO ] An instance is already running. Exiting the Salt Minion
[INFO ] Shutting down the Salt Minion
The Salt Minion is shutdown.
```

/etc/salt/minion.d # systemctl status salt-minion

```
● salt-minion.service - The Salt Minion
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/salt-minion.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-07-03 09:11:51 CEST; 14h ago
Main PID: 33166 (salt-minion)
Tasks: 3
CGroup: /system.slice/salt-minion.service
├─31676 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/salt-minion
└─31681 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/salt-minion

[ERROR ] Error while bringing up minion for multi-master. Is master at host.name.com >
Error while bringing up minion for multi-master. Is master at host.name.com >
salt-minion[ERROR ][31681] Error while bringing up minion for multi-master. Is master at host.name.com responding?
salt-minion[ERROR ][31686] Minion unable to successfully connect to a Salt Master.
```

salt-call -l debug state.apply

```
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: host.name.com
[WARNING ] Insecure logging configuration detected! Sensitive data may be logged.
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] Grains refresh requested. Refreshing grains.
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'core' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'disks' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'extra' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'lvm' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'mdadm' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'minion_process' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'opts' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] Override  __utils__: <module 'salt.loaded.int.grains.zfs' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/grains/zfs.py'>
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'zfs' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'zfs' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded zfs.is_supported
[DEBUG   ] Connecting to master. Attempt 1 of 1
[DEBUG   ] Master URI: tcp://111.111.111:4506
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new AsyncAuth for ('/etc/salt/pki/minion', 'host.name.com, 'tcp:// 111.111.111:4506')
[DEBUG   ] Generated random reconnect delay between '1000ms' and '11000ms' (4460)
[DEBUG   ] Setting zmq_reconnect_ivl to '4460ms'
[DEBUG   ] Setting zmq_reconnect_ivl_max to '11000ms'
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt.get_rsa_key: Loading private key
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt._get_key_with_evict: Loading private key
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_fcss67juz4_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ fcss67juz4_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt.get_rsa_pub_key: Loading public key
[DEBUG   ] Closing AsyncReqChannel instance
Unable to sign_in to master: Attempt to authenticate with the salt master failed with timeout error
```

Any idea ?

Many Thanks
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is the service was already running.

> An instance is already running. Exiting the Salt Minion

The seconds problem is the master was not responding. Is it running, and is there a firewall blocking it?

> Is master at host.name.com responding?